# GitLab CI docker build - docker: not found - exit code 127

Tags: java, docker, maven, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to create a CI/CD Pipeline for a simple java/maven project.
The runner that I'm using is a docker runner.
I'm using a `dockerfile` to create a container which installs maven/java/etc.. and in this container the program should be tested.

Sorry for the question but I am new to CI/CD Pipelines in GitLab.

GitHub works just fine have a look: https://github.com/ni920/CICD-Test

Thank you

---

Here are the CI logs

```sh
...
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
 $ docker build --build-arg JAVA_VERSION=openjdk7
 /bin/sh: eval: line 95: docker: not found
Cleaning up file based variables
 ERROR: Job failed: exit code 127
```

---

Thats the `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
stages:
  - java7
# - java11
# - deploy


java7:
  stage: java7
  script:
      - docker build --build-arg JAVA_VERSION=openjdk7
 # tags:
 #   - docker

#java11:
#  stage: java11
#  script:
#    - docker build --build-arg JAVA_VERSION=openjdk11
#  tags:
#    - docker
```

---

Thats the `dockerfile`

```
# Pull base image.
FROM alpine as build

ARG MAVEN_VERSION=3.6.1
ARG USER_HOME_DIR="/root"
ARG JAVA_VERSION=openjdk7
ARG BASE_URL=https://apache.osuosl.org/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries

ENV HTTP_PROXY=#comment
ENV HTTPS_PROXY=#comment

# Install Java.
RUN apk --update --no-cache add JAVA_VERSION curl

RUN mkdir -p /usr/share/maven /usr/share/maven/ref \
 && curl -fsSL -o /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz ${BASE_URL}/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz \
 && tar -xzf /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz -C /usr/share/maven --strip-components=1 \
 && rm -f /tmp/apache-maven.tar.gz \
 && ln -s /usr/share/maven/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

# Define working directory.
WORKDIR /data

# Define commonly used JAVA_HOME variable
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/default-jvm/

# Define default command.
CMD ["mvn", "--version"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running your pipelines using the **Docker** *executor* means that your jobs will run in a **Docker container**, but not that you will be able to execute `docker` commands.

If you need to run `docker` commands inside a **GitLab CI** *job* (read *"inside a container"*) you will need **Docker-in-Docker** (often abbreviated *DinD*). It is a vast topic on itself but you can get started with **GitLab CI**'s documentation: [Use Docker to build Docker images](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/docker/using_docker_build.html)

---

I always use *DinD* and have a minimal setup in my **gitlab-ci.yml**.

Using a [docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker) image as a default:

```yaml
image: docker:19.03.13
```

Define a default variable for **TLS** certificates:

```yaml
variables:
    DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: "/certs"
```

Then use a docker image as a service to enable *DinD*:

```yaml
services:
    -   name: docker:19.03.13-dind
        alias: docker
```

---

I wrote [a few posts](https://aymdev.io/en/blog/search/keyword/GitLab%20CI) about using **Docker-in-Docker** on **GitLab CI** that you may find useful, but I still recommend to extensively read **GitLab**'s documentation before reading them.